# Loop through array of objects (PHP)

Tags: arrays, wordpress

I have been trying to loop through this array but I simply cannot retrieve the post title. Its probably a little something I am missing but I can't get it right.

```
Array
(
[0] => WP_Post Object
    (
        [ID] => 5366
        [post_author] => 1
        [post_date] => 2013-07-09 12:06:00
        [post_date_gmt] => 2013-07-09 12:06:00
        [post_content] => 
        [post_title] => Mini Face Lift
        [post_excerpt] => 
        [post_status] => publish
        [comment_status] => open
        [ping_status] => open
        [post_password] => 
        [post_name] => mini-face-lift
        [to_ping] => 
        [pinged] => 
        [post_modified] => 2013-07-09 12:06:00
        [post_modified_gmt] => 2013-07-09 12:06:00
        [post_content_filtered] => 
        [post_parent] => 17
    )
    )
```

If I want to get the post title -- how do I do it? I'd really appreciate your help as I am stuck.

Huge thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not a multi-dimensional array, but an array of objects . . . try something like:

`$varName[0]->post_title`

Alternatively:

`$varName[0]['post_title']`

If you're trying to iterate and get each title, you probably want something like:

```
foreach ($varName as $key=>$wpPostObject) {
    echo $wpPostObject->post_title;
}
```

Comment: You're an absolute star! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$examplePost = get_post(); //Post object you are retrieving

echo apply_filters( 'single_post_title', $examplePost->post_title ); //echos the post name, use the_content instead, if you are doing this in the loop
```